# Smart contract Token distribution solution

Tags: smartcontracts

I have a question regard to the token sale: How token distribution work?

An example:

```
10% for private sale
30% for public sale 
20% for dev team
40% for rewards
```

The number of token will be transferred to these address at the time the token created or it will be transferred to these address after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the token contract implementation, can be both.

Example that mints 100 tokens to public sale available right after token creation, and reserves another 50 for later vesting by a dev team address:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyToken {
    mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
    mapping (address => Vesting) _vesting;
    
    struct Vesting {
        uint256 amount;
        uint64 unlockTime;
    }
    
    constructor() {
        address publicSaleAddress = address(0x123);
        address devTeamAddress = address(0x456);
        
        // set the `publicSaleAddress` balance right away
        _balances[publicSaleAddress] = 100;

        // don't set the `devTeamAddress` balance now
        // instead, allow them to claim it after some time
        uint64 deadline = uint64(block.timestamp) + 365 days;
        _vesting[devTeamAddress] = Vesting(
            50,
           deadline
        );
    }
    
    function unvest() external {
        // check if they have something to unvest
        require(_vesting[msg.sender].amount > 0, 'Nothing to unvest');
        
        // check if they are allowed to unvest yet
        require(_vesting[msg.sender].unlockTime >= block.timestamp, 'Not yet');
        
        // increase their balance
        _balances[msg.sender] += _vesting[msg.sender].amount;
        
        // prevent them from claiming the balance again
        _vesting[msg.sender] = Vesting(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Petr Hejda. A quick one, for rewards token, should I keep it in Token address and create a claim function for user to claim their reward or transfer those token to another smart contract address like TokenABCReward?

Comment: @DonerKebab Both ways are valid.